# Code after Splitter with aggregation strategy is not executed if exception in inner route were handled (Apache Camel)

Tags: apache-camel

I've faced with behavior that I can't understand. This issue happens when Split with AggregationStrategy is executed and during one of the iterations, an exception occurs. An exception occurs inside of Splitter in another route (direct endpoint which is called for each iteration). Seems like route execution stops just after Splitter.

Here is sample code.

This is a route that builds one report per each client and collects names of files for internal statistics.

```java
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
    public class ReportRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    
      ClientRepository clientRepository;
    
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:handleError")); //handles an error, adds error message to internal error collector for statistic and writes log
    
        from("direct:generateReports")
        
            .setProperty("reportTask", body()) //at this point there is in the body an object of type ReportTask, containig all data required for building report
    
            .bean(clientRepository, "getAllClients") // Body is a List<Client>
            
            .split(body())
              .aggregationStrategy(new FileNamesListAggregationStrategy())
              .to("direct:generateReportForClient") // creates report which is saved in the file system. uses the same error handler
            .end()
            
            //when an exception occurs during split then code after splitter is not executed
    
            .log("Finished generating reports. Files created ${body}"); // Body has to be List<String> with file names.
      }
    }
```

AggregationStrategy is pretty simple - it just extracts the name of the file. If the header is absent it returns NULL.

```java
    public class FileNamesListAggregationStrategy extends AbstractListAggregationStrategy<String> {
    
      @Override
      public String getValue(Exchange exchange) {
        Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();
        return inMessage.getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class);
      }
    }
```

When everything goes smoothly after splitting there is in the Body List with all file names. But when in the route "direct:generateReportForClient" some exception occurred (I've added error simulation for one client) than aggregated body just contains one less file name -it's OK (everything was aggregated correctly).

BUT just after Split after route execution stops and result that is in the body at this point (List with file names) is returned to the client (FluentProducer) which expects ReportTask as a response body.

and it tries to convert value - List (aggregated result) to ReportTask and it causes `org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type`

Why route breaks after split? All errors were handled and aggregation finished correctly.

PS I've read Camel In Action book and Documentation about Splitter but I haven't found the answer.

PPS project runs on Spring Boot 2.3.1 and Camel 3.3.0

**UPDATE**
This route is started by FluentProducerTemplate

```java
    ReportTask processedReportTask = producer.to("direct:generateReports")
            .withBody(reportTask)
            .request(ReportTask.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is error handler + custom aggregation strategy in the split.

From Camel in Action book (5.3.5):

> WARNING   When using a custom AggregationStrategy with the Splitter,
> it’s important to know that you’re responsible for handling
> exceptions. If you don’t propagate the exception back, the Splitter
> will assume you’ve handled the exception and will ignore it.

In your code, you use the aggregation strategy extended from `AbstractListAggregationStrategy`. Let's look to `aggregate` method in `AbstractListAggregationStrategy`:

```java
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    List<V> list;

    if (oldExchange == null) {
        list = getList(newExchange);
    } else {
        list = getList(oldExchange);
    }

    if (newExchange != null) {
        V value = getValue(newExchange);
        if (value != null) {
            list.add(value);
        }
    }

    return oldExchange != null ? oldExchange : newExchange;
}
```

If a first exchange is handled by error handler we will have in result exchange (`newExchange`) number of properties set by Error Handler (`Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exchange.FAILURE_ENDPOINT,  Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED and Exchange.FAILURE_HANDLED`) and `exchange.errorHandlerHandled=true`. Methods `getErrorHandlerHandled()/setErrorHandlerHandled(Boolean errorHandlerHandled)` are available in `ExtendedExchange` interface.

In this case, your split finishes with an exchange with `errorHandlerHandled=true` and it breaks the route.

The reason is described in [camel exception clause manual](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html#ExceptionClause-WhatistheDifferenceBetweenHandledandContinued)

> If handled is true, then the thrown exception will be handled and
> Camel will not continue routing in the original route, but break out.

To prevent this behaviour you can cast your exchange to `ExtendedExchange` and set `errorHandlerHandled=false` in the aggregation strategy `aggregate` method. And your route won't be broken but will be continued.

```java
  @Override
  public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    Exchange aggregatedExchange = super.aggregate(oldExchange, newExchange);
    ((ExtendedExchange) aggregatedExchange).setErrorHandlerHandled(false);
    return aggregatedExchange;
  }
```

The tricky situation is that if you have exchange handled by Error Handler as **not a first one** in your aggregation strategy you won't face any issue. Because camel will use the **first** exchange(without `errorHandlerHandled=true`) as a base for aggregation.

Comment: As I met this problem with Camel version 2, I decided to share how to solve this issue with Camel version 2 as well.

I found useful code snippets in [Apache Camel 3.x Upgrade Guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_1.html#_api_changes)

For version 2 fix looks like:
`oldExchange.setProperty(Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED, false);`

And for version 3 it is better to use adapt() instead of casting:
`oldExchange.adapt(ExtendedExchange.class)
            .setErrorHandlerHandled(false);`

Comment: One more update. At least in Camel 3.10.0 (maybe a little bit earlier) structure of exchange properties has been changed. Now "system" (means "camel") properties are stored separately from "users" properties. 

You need to add code:

`aggregatedExchange.setProperty(FAILURE_HANDLED, false);`